# How to get the path of a key deeply embedded (debugging in Chrome)...Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser

In FireFox, as you dig into an object and traverse from one key to another, at some point the eureka moment comes... you find the key you are looking for and if you right click on the key you get an option that says "Get Path".  You click on it and your clipText receives the path which represents the hard work you did carving up the hierarchy.  I am talking about a direct path from the originating obj ref like "request" in the case below to "raw"  or "***request.options.operation.resultSet.records[0].raw***"  Direct path to destination...

[image]

Does Chrome have anything of the sort... maybe done some other way???  Or is there some better object inspector which can save the path where you are, so you don't have to blunder again and again until you record the exact path.